# How to make Electron window object accessible from within async function without global?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, electron

I am trying to make an instance of the BrowserWindow object in an Electron app accessible to app's menu, so a menu command can use the reference to open an IndexedDB database. Because I'm instantiating the mainWindow within an immediately invoked async function, it's not clear how to best make that object available in code within a required file.

index.js (main process)

```
let mainWindow;
//other code here

(async () => {
    await app.whenReady();
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);

    mainWindow = await createMainWindow();
    //make mainWindow available in required menu.js file
    //so it can be referenced from menu command
    //to access indexedDB database

})();
```

I would like the object to be accessible in menu.js, which is required by index.js.

```
    //menu setup
    {
        label: "Add Item to Database",
        click() {
                  //undefined unless object can be imported
                  //dialog code for inputting data to be added
                  mainWindow.webContents.send("addItem", data);
                }
    },
```

I could store mainWindow in a global object but I'm trying to avoid that. I could also create a method on the Menu object and store it there since that's accessible in menu.js. I'm not sure if that's a good idea though. And I suppose I could simply add the menu.js code into index.js since mainWindow would be in scope and would have been assigned by the time the menu command is used. But I'm assuming there's a better way to do this. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

To pass an object around, without the use of globals, the general pattern is to use function arguments.

It looks like `menu.js` exports an `object` now. Instead, you can export a function that *returns* that object instead.

Then, instead of calling `Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);`, you would call     `Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu(mainWindow));` and you are good to go.

Here's an example of `menu.js`:

```js
module.exports = (mainWindow) => {
  label: "Add Item to Database",
  click: ()  => {
    //undefined unless object can be imported
    //dialog code for inputting data to be added
    mainWindow.webContents.send("addItem", data);
  }
};
```

Comment: That doesn't work. menu is not a function; it's an object. `mainWindow = await createMainWindow();
 Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu(mainWindow));` produces a type error.

Comment: @Dotnaught, yes you should change menu to a function that _returns_ the object. I made a typo in my answer though, so I hope that didn't confuse things. (fixed now)

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand but I tried creating a function so that `Menu.setApplicationMenu(returnMenu(mainWindow));` takes mainWindow as a parameter and returns the menu object. But I don't see how mainWindow becomes accessible in the menu.js scope since Menu.setApplicationMenu runs in the parent file, index.js. mainWindow is still undefined in menu.js.

Comment: Are you defining `returnMenu` in `menu.js` ?

Comment: @Dotnaught added an example.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up fixing it with something like what you suggested -- exporting a function from menu.js to pass the mainWindow object from index.js to a variable in menu.js.